# Preposition unter in figurative sense means grasp?

Tags: preposition

*Was verstehen Sie unter Yoga?* To me this means "What do you know about yoga?" or "What does yoga mean to you?" Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A noun is a name for something. Such a name assembles images, associations, connotations and relations between parts of named thing. All of that is more specific than the name and comes *under* that thing.

> Was verstehen Sie unter Yoga?

means: *What do you understand by Yoga?* or *What do you mean by Yoga?*

So

> What does Yoga mean to you?

comes close. But I as a none-native English speaker would read that question as something like *Does Yoga mean a lot to you?* and in German the question has nothing to do with that.

> What do you know about Yoga?

would be something like

> Was verstehen Sie *von* Yoga? (*at what level are you*)

or

> Was *wissen* Sie *über* Yoga?

So if you will: *Have you thought about the categorial aspects of Yoga?*

---

The preposition *unter* itself has no other meaning than *under, below, ...*.

Answer (score 3):

> What does yoga mean to you?

comes closer to what I would understand as the meaning of the question (Was ich unter dieser Frage verstehe.):

> Was verstehen Sie unter Yoga?

It would not specifically mean

> What do you know about Yoga?

although the person who asks this question might imply that someone is not specific/informed enough when they talk, e.g., about yoga,

Maybe think about “unter” as asking for the underlying definition.

Answer (score 3):

> Was verstehen Sie unter Yoga?

If the question is meant literally this would be translated as "What do you understand by (the term) yoga?" and a possible answer would be "It's an old Indian set of practices ...", and of course the answer can be long, but the question really is just asking for a definition from the view of the person that is asked. "Was verstehen Sie unter ... " is often used when the definition of a word is unclear or the word is used differently by different persons:

> Was verstehen Sie unter Sozialismus?
> Was verstehen Sie unter Pfannkuchen?

Since the definition of yoga is pretty clear to most people, this particular question could also be meant less literally, as a more personal question, in the sense of "What does yoga mean to you?", where a possible answer could be "For me, it's great way to relax and work out." In that case, a better way to put it would be "Was bedeutet Yoga für Sie?" though.

I wouldn't translate it as "What do you know about yoga?", which, at least in its literal sense, is a much more general question ("Was wissen Sie über Yoga?" or maybe "Was verstehen Sie von Yoga?" - note the "von" instead of "unter").